# "To a bar" vs "A bar" as an answer to "Where did they go?"

Tags: prepositions, questions, responses

Can the preposition "to" be left out in a short answer to the question "Where did they go?"? Should it be "To a bar." or "A bar."? I am not sure because the question doesn't end with "to".

Does it apply to other prepositions?

Comment: You don’t need to follow the part of speech of the interrogative adverb.

Comment: Not from a full sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But one of these would be better:

> Where did they go?
> **To** a bar.

or

> Where did they go **to**?
> A bar.

But you can omit or double up **to** without any loss of meaning.